# Gob Отправляет пустую структуру на сервер

Tags: golang, struct, binary

Пытаюсь отправить вложенную структуру на сервер, но получаю `&{{[0 0] [0 0]}}`.

**client.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

type Header struct {
    h_type   [2]uint8
    h_method [2]uint8
}

type Request struct {
    MM Header
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Client")
    //create structure object
    studentEncode := Request{
        MM: Header{
            h_type:   [2]uint8{0x0, 0xEC},
            h_method: [2]uint8{0x0, 0xA1},
        },
    }

    fmt.Println("start client")
    // dial TCP connection
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Connection error", err)
    }
    //Create encoder object, We are passing connection object in Encoder
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
    // Encode Structure, IT will pass student object over TCP connection
    encoder.Encode(studentEncode)
    // close connection
    conn.Close()
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

**server.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type Header struct {
    h_type   [2]uint8
    h_method [2]uint8
}

type Request struct {
    MM Header
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    // create new decoder object and provide connection
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(conn)
    // create blank student object
    p := &Request{}
    // decode serialize data
    dec.Decode(p)
    // print
    fmt.Println(p)
    // close connection for that client
    conn.Close()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Server")
    // start TCP server and listen on port 8080
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        panic(err)
    }
    for {
        // this blocks until connection or error
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
            continue
        }
        // a goroutine handles conn so that the loop can accept other connections
        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, наверное из-за вложенности структуры или неправильного декодирования.

При структуре Standalone проблем не происходит.

```
type Standalone struct {
    Name string
    Prefix string
}
```

Comment: У вас же имена не экспортированы.

Comment: @Ainar-G то есть имена не экспортированы? не очень понял вас

Comment: Я ответил на ваш вопрос, но ещё крайне рекомендую почитать хоть какую-нибудь книгу про го. Иначе вы как будто задаёте вопросы про интегралы, не зная, что такое сложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и в любых пакетах сериализации, ваши данные должны быть экспортированы, чтобы пакет мог с ними работать. Так что:

```
type Header struct {
    HType   [2]uint8
    HMethod [2]uint8
}
```

Идентификаторы, начинающиеся с маленькой буквы, недоступны для других пакетов.